# Mssql Update From join 1 to many

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

I am using a join (1 to many--- Table A -> Table B) to Update Table A. 
But it overrides my value in Table A in the end.

UPDATE A SET A.VAL = A.VAL + B.VAL JOIN A,B ON....

Join
A.VAL |B.VAL1
A.VAL |B.VAL2

After Update -- A.VAL becomes like this
A.VAL + B.VAL2

I need A.VAL + B.VAL1 + B.VAL2 how can i do this

Comment: At least I have no idea what you're asking. Maybe you should include example + expected results and please, no pictures

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:-

```
UPDATE A JOIN B ON A.VAL = B.VAL1 AND A.VAL = B.VAL2
SET A.VAL = A.VAL + B.VAL1 + B.VAL2
```